# How To Get 32 Bit Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

Where can I download the 32-bit ISO of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Both desktop and server iso of Ubuntu are available at [Ubuntu releases](http://releases.ubuntu.com).

In your case, for a **32-bit desktop version** you can download `ubuntu-16.04-desktop-i386.iso`

Here, *i386*    --> 32-bit
And,  *amd64*--> 64-bit

Also you can choose a *direct download*

or

*download torrent file for the same* and then download the whole iso file through torrent

Answer (score 0):

If you're on an x86 (normal PC) 32-bit system, [you can click here to download the ISO](http://mirror.pnl.gov/releases/16.04.1/ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-i386.iso).

If for some reason you want Ubuntu 16.10, which requires more work from you since you have to take the effort to upgrade it to Ubuntu 17.04 by July of 2017, [you can click here to download the ISO](http://mirror.pnl.gov/releases/16.10/ubuntu-16.10-desktop-i386.iso).

For future reference, you can get it by going to [ubuntu.com](https://www.ubuntu.com/) and [clicking on Download in the upper right](https://www.ubuntu.com/download).